# C# Regular Expression to comment out console.log

Tags: c#, regex

I have build a small deployment .exe in c# to do a few things like combine and min my JS and CSS.

One thing I need is a regular expression that I can use to comment out all console.log statements in my JavaScript files.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Can you explain where exactly you are having difficulties? We will not write your code for you, in particular if you don't actually ask a question.

Comment: I wasnt trying a regular expression before.  I was just replacing console.log with //console.log. The problem with that is that there can be JS on the same line therefore I need to instead do something like /*console.log('foo');*/

Comment: Why do you need to comment them all out?

Comment: Because it can't be in my production JS files for a lot of reasons.  It is just for debugging, not all browsers support it

Comment: And overriding it with your own mock `console.log` will not work?

Comment: It will but I rather just comment it out, then when I minify it it will be gone...and reduce the size of my code as well

Comment: "The problem with that is that there can be JS on the same line"  Don't put multiple lines of code on the same physical line.

Comment: Steve - I agree but some of this is already minified code.  I guess I could unminify it first, might just overload the console.  Most likely that is the safest play here.

Answer (score 1):

This can get you started:

```
var str = "hello console.log('hello'); bye";
var replaced = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<log>console\.log\(.*?\);?)", @"/* ${log} */");
```

Basically what we are doing is looking for instance of `console.log(...)` with a non-greedy capture between the parenthesis, and optionally capture the semicolon after `console.log`.

Note that if your call to `console.log`'s content includes parens, like `console.log('Hello (bye)');`, then this doesn't handle that - but you should be able to tweak it to get that much working.